# I'm having trouble getting my flex items to align properly

Tags: html, css

I've been messing around with `flex` for a while now but not getting the results I want. What I'm trying to do is create a web page with 6 divs per row. I want each div to have `height: 185px` and `width: 265px` but for some reason when I use `flex-wrap: wrap` it stretches my divs out and makes them bigger. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to keep the divs the size that I want?

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 185px;
  width: 265px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="content">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: First, you can't fit 6 boxes in a row with width `265px` and a container width `1200px`. So the maximum number of boxes you can fit inside the container per row is 4 only. So 4*265px will be 1060px excluding the margin. So you can't fit another box in the same row.

Comment: as saying abin, there is a math problem: 6 x 265 = 1590, and you want a max width of 1200! Otherwise, use grid with a grid template column like repeat(6,265px)

Comment: Without `flex-wrap`, flex will want to squeeze all items into one line, no matter what width you set. As an aside, I recommend using `gap` instead of margin.